# Search box result with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am setting up a search using bootstrap, and I would like to display the results in an overlay around the search field, however I am not sure how to do it.

I'm using Bootstrap 4, so I don't even know where to start.
I wanted to try to do something with just HTML and CSS.

A bit similar to searching for the bootstrap documentation itself.

So I would like to display the overlay around the search box.
I don't know how I could make this search result overlay appear over all the content, but just below the search box.
And also that it would grow according to the size of the number of results.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried select2.js (https://select2.org/)? They have a Bootstrap 4 theme you can use (https://github.com/ttskch/select2-bootstrap4-theme).

Comment: [Twitter typeahead plugin](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) might be worth checking out. You can style the overlay any way you want... doesn't require bootstrap

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips.
The search javascript, I already did (I'm using angular).

Except that as I don't know much about CSS, I'm not able to make this box effect around and displaying it over the other components.

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery UI's [autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Implementing is easy.

```
    var yourSuggestions = [
        "Suggestion 1",
        "Suggestion 2",
        "Another suggestion"
        //so on...
      ];

    $("#searchWord").autocomplete({
       source: yourSuggestions
    });
```

Here's a **[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/6rtbe5uL/)**. Play around it and you can see how things work. In this example bootstrap, jQuery and jQuery UI was used.